# MySQL JOIN without any JOIN predicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
`table_1`

+----+----------+
| id | value    |
+----+----------+
|  1 | value_1  |
|  2 | value_2  |
| 10 | value_10 |
| 20 | value_20 |
| 50 | value_50 |
+----+----------+
```

---

```
`table_2`

+----+----------+
| id | value    |
+----+----------+
|  1 | value_1  |
|  2 | value_2  |
| 10 | value_10 |
| 20 | value_20 |
| 50 | value_50 |
+----+----------+
```

Now I ran the following query:

```
UPDATE table_1, table_2 SET table_1.value = 'updated' WHERE table_1.id = '20';
```

I got the following result:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.45 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Now if I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE table_1.id = '20';
```

I get 5 rows:

```
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

which is very much correct.

Why the `UPDATE` query not behaving in similar way to `SELECT`? 
Is there any generic way of transforming the above `UPDATE` query into `SELECT` query so that we can get the affected row count without actually executing the `UPDATE` query?

In the above case we should get 1 on both queries.

Comment: You only update table1 fiedl not table2 and you retrieve both table data so different is there

Answer (score 2):

The affected row count is correct as is the number of rows returned by the `select`.

This is quite clearly explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named
>   in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is
>   updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times.

The `select` is returning the same row from `table1` multiple times.  Regardless, this row only gets updated once by the `update`.  Which value it gets (if there is a choice) is arbitrary.  You should not depend on a particular behavior.  And, the updates are not cumulative.

Answer (score 0):

when you added :

```
,table2
```

you have made a join, that's why you have so much columns...
but if yu want edit your 2 tables row at the same time, use this :

```
UPDATE table_1, table_2 SET table_1.value = 'updated', table_2.value = 'updated' WHERE table_1.id = '20';
```